# VBA WORD 2019 Redesigned comments. Looking for an Event like "Comment was added" or "Comment has changed" to autocorrect comment text afterwards

Tags: vba, events, ms-word

In 2019 comments in Word were redesigned. Therefore there was no autocorrection available in comments anymore.
I used the autocorrection function for substituting my own abbreviations in the comments.
I now wrote a VBA SUB making use of the Comments/Comment object and the AutoCorrect object.
It works fine to substitute my abbreviations in all comments after I wrote them. But to get a more immediate experience, I would like to link the SUB to a "Comment was added"- or "Comment has changed"-Event but I can't find one.
The closest I can get is via a call of my SUB in App_WindowSelectionChange() but the selection of a comment balloon or adding a new comment is not firing that event.

It should work like this:

editing autocorrection fu1 = fuggel1

Select: Word->Developement tools->macros-> Register_Event_Handler()

write comment including "fu1 is the best"

on event changing to "fuggel1 is the best"

Any ideas how to make the call of my SUB related to adding a new comment or changing a comment ?

```
Rem Class EventACC
Public WithEvents App As Word.Application

Private Sub App_WindowSelectionChange(ByVal Sel As Selection)
Rem Debug.Print ("change")
Call Auto_Correct_Comment
End Sub
```

```
Rem Module AutoCorrectComment

Dim ACC As New EventACC

Sub Register_Event_Handler()
 Set ACC.App = Word.Application
End Sub

Sub Auto_Correct_Comment()
    If ActiveDocument.Comments.Count >= 1 Then
        For X = 1 To ActiveDocument.Comments.Count
        Dim m_s_comment As String
        Dim m_s_arr_comment_p() As String
        m_s_comment = Trim(ActiveDocument.Comments(X).Range.Text)
        m_s_arr_comment_p = Split(m_s_comment, " ")
            For C = 0 To UBound(m_s_arr_comment_p)
                Rem Debug.Print (m_s_arr_comment_p(C))
                On Error Resume Next
                Dim m_s_test As String
                m_s_test = AutoCorrect.Entries(m_s_arr_comment_p(C)).Value
                If Err.Number = 0 Then
                    Rem Debug.Print (AutoCorrect.Entries(m_s_arr_comment_p(C)).Value)
                    m_s_comment = Replace(m_s_comment, m_s_arr_comment_p(C), AutoCorrect.Entries(m_s_arr_comment_p(C)).Value)
                    Rem Debug.Print (m_s_comment)
                End If
            Next C
        ActiveDocument.Comments(X).Range.Text = m_s_comment
        Next X
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I made some progess, now being able to change abbreviations in the selected comment via a key-shortcut (ALT + 0) after writing and confirming it or choosing the comment balloon later on. See code below. Still wanting an event related change.

Usage->Select: Word->Developement tools->macros->AddKeyBinding().
Then use the Key-Shortcut (Alt+0) on comments after writing and confirming them.

```
Rem Module AutoCorrectComment
Sub Auto_Correct_Comment_2()
If ActiveDocument.ActiveWindow.ActivePane.Selection.Comments.Count >= 1 Then
        m_s_comment = Trim(ActiveDocument.ActiveWindow.ActivePane.Selection.Comments.Item(1).Range.Text)
        m_s_comment_copy = m_s_comment
        Replacement = Array(".", ",", "?", "!", ":") ' add more
            For Each A In Replacement
                m_s_comment_copy = Replace(m_s_comment_copy, A, " " & A & " ") ' necessary to "free" Autocorrect Element
            Next A
        m_s_arr_comment_p = Split(m_s_comment_copy, " ")
        For C = 0 To UBound(m_s_arr_comment_p)
                    Rem Debug.Print (m_s_arr_comment_p(C))
                    On Error Resume Next
                    Dim m_s_test As String
                    m_s_test = AutoCorrect.Entries(m_s_arr_comment_p(C)).Value
                    If Err.Number = 0 Then
                        Debug.Print (m_s_arr_comment_p(C))
                        Rem Debug.Print (AutoCorrect.Entries(m_s_arr_comment_p(C)).Value)
                        m_s_comment = Replace(m_s_comment, m_s_arr_comment_p(C), AutoCorrect.Entries(m_s_arr_comment_p(C)).Value)
                        Rem Debug.Print (m_s_comment)
                    End If
                Next C
            ActiveDocument.ActiveWindow.ActivePane.Selection.Comments.Item(1).Range.Text = m_s_comment
    End If
End Sub


Sub AddKeyBinding()
    With Application
         
        .CustomizationContext = ActiveDocument.AttachedTemplate

         ' \\ Add keybinding to Active.Document Shorcut: Alt+0
        .KeyBindings.Add KeyCode:=BuildKeyCode(wdKeyAlt, wdKey0), _
        KeyCategory:=wdKeyCategoryCommand, _
        Command:="Auto_Correct_Comment_2"
    End With
End Sub
```